# How to scrape data selectively from tables in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a small project of my own and try to wrap my mind around web scraping.

I am using Python 2 and BeautifulSoap module(but tried other modules as well, experimenting with re module, others).

Briefly, given the website: http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/exchange/daily-closing-past-five-day/ I would like to gather the information about the exchange rates for each Currency but with more flexible code.

Here is my example:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string
import re

myurl = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/exchange/daily-closing-past-five-day/'
soup  = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(myurl).read(), "lxml")

dataTables = soup.find_all('td')

brandNewList = []

for x in dataTables:
    text = x.get_text().strip()
    brandNewList.append(text)
    #print  text

for index, item in enumerate(brandNewList):
    if item == "U.S. dollar (close)":
        for item in brandNewList[index:6]:
            print item
```

It displays:

```
$ python crawler.py
U.S. dollar (close)
1.4530
1.4557
1.4559
1.4490
1.4279
```

So, as you may see, I can display the data corresponding to each currency by scraping the 'td' tags; I can get even more specific if I would use 'th' in combination with 'td' tags.
But, what if I don't really want to specify the exact string "U.S. dollar (close)", how can I make the script mode adaptable to different websites?
For example, I would like enter as an argument from the terminal only "US"/"us" and the script will give me back the values corresponding to the US dollar independently on how the column is named on different websites?

Also, I am kind of a beginner in Python so can you, please show me the more neat way of re-writing my web crawler? It feels like I have written it in a kind of "dumb" way, mostly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I make the script mode adaptable to different websites?

*Different sites have really different markups*, it is close to impossible to make a universal and *reliable* location mechanism in your case. Depending on how many sites you want to scrape, you may just loop over the different locating functions with an [EAFP approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) until you successfully get the currency rate.

Note that some resources provide public or private APIs and you don't really need to scrape them.

By the way, you can improve your code by locating the `U.S. dollar (close)` label and getting the [following `td` siblings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
us_dollar_label = soup.find("td", text="U.S. dollar (close)")
rates = [td.get_text() for td in us_dollar_label.find_next_siblings("td")]
```

Comment: or, cool, I didn't hear about EAFP before; learned something new today :), thanks

Comment: or, that's neat - thanks for the snippet ; now, this looks more of a python-way of getting the info